# Why browser is not throwing exception for syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I accidentally wrote a wrong JavaScript syntax (I think so).

code is

```
  var temp = {};
    temp.a = 34;
    height:34, //should fail here.
    temp.b = 56;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdQ5Y/)

is syntax is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A colon can be used to [label a statement](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/statements/label.php), and that's what's happening here. There are no errors in your code, it's intended behavior.

Edit: [better resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) on labels. :)